# ReferenceError: ActiveXObject is not defined in Chrome and Mozilla

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, activexobject, referenceerror

I am having a lot of difficulty attempting to solve a **ReferenceError**:

> ActiveXObject is not defined in Google Chrome.

```
function WriteToFile()
{
  var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
  var s = fso.CreateTextFile("/var/www/html/nodejsphp/Test.txt",true);
  s.WriteLine('messages');
  console.log("contents of file now'some sampletext'");
  s.Close();
}
```

Any idea where to begin?

Answer (score 3):

That's because Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox (and Microsoft Edge) don't support `ActiveXObject`, and never have, and never will. ActiveX has no place in modern web browsers.

Only IE supports `ActiveXObject`, and even then, more recent versions of IE only support it with a subset of objects (I don't think `FileSystemObject` is one of them).

As for creating a text file on the local machine's file system from a web page: Nope, you can't do that. (Except in old versions of IE with security disabled.)

Comment: *"Only IE supports `ActiveXObject`"* Doesn't Opera support `ActiveXObject`?

Comment: @AnnZen - Current Opera certainly doesn't. It could be that some old version of it did, at least in some limited form (for instance, maybe just `new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")` to create an `XMLHttpRequest` object for backward-compatibility with MS-only sites from the late 90's), but I don't recall that being the case (not that I'd necessarily have reason to).